# How to use Kazam

Tags: kazam

How to use `Kazam` screen recording application ?

I installed it. I can see Count Down also when I try to run it. But where is the Video storing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start kazam. Go to File=>Preferences. Under the Screencast and Screenshot tabs, you can enable auto save and specify where to save the files. Otherwise, when you "finish" recording (from the panel icon menu) or take a screenshot, kazam will ask you whether and where to save the file.

Comment: Thannks @jeffas. Kazam is not asking anything.

Comment: Have you set auto save?

Comment: Thanks @jeffas. Yes, I set auto save.

Comment: In that case, kazam will save files in the directory specified in the preferences, as I said in my original answer.